# Wi-Fi Hotspot File Transfer If IP Address is available

Tags: android, hotspot

I want to transfer files over Wi-Fi hotspot between two android device.I am having IP Address and MAC address of the receiver device using WI-Fi manager but don't know the way how to transfer files over this IP address from SDCARD of the sender device . Please help...

Comment: please put some code of whatever you tried.

Comment: Dear Mayank, I used WIFIManager Class to get the list of devices on which hotspot is on and its giving me IP address , MAC address but I don't know how to transfer files over this IP address and MAC address.

Comment: I think one device has to be a server, and the other - a client. Client connects to the server and sends files.

Comment: This might help you : http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/01/file-transfer-via-socket-between.html